# Using geometry nodes to scatter objects disables hair particle systems

Tags: rendering, particles, geometry-nodes, hair

I am using a hair particle system to scatter grass around an object, as well as geometry nodes to scatter kelp (since the kept itself has a hair particle system that can't be scattered with another hair particle system)

Whenever I enable the geometry node modifier, the hair system immediately disappears, without being hidden. This also happens in the final render. I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it, does anyone have an idea?

(I do not want to just duplicate the emitter object or make instances real which would add more vertices to the scene, I just want the two systems to display at the same time)

Here's a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15GdfFWw8qeAGsJcFazy2P6jk9o1Of1Wp/view?usp=share_link) showing the issue

I have attached an example file with this issue below for you to mess around with:

[image]

Comment: Do you need the particle system to be on top of the modifier stack?

Comment: The position of the particle system doesn't change anything, sadly

Comment: set the particle system first in the stack, and in the GN, realize instances before joining them back to the input mesh.

Comment: Converting any instance to a real object won't work, as it would add way too much geometry to the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After batteling with this for months I finally realized that, in short - you can't fix this.
Blender just can't deal with particle systems on geometry scatter nodes.
The way I solved it was by duplicating the emitter object and having one of them emit the actual grass hair system, and using the other one to scatter objects with the geometry nodes, then hiding one of the emitters in the render.

This is a very unclean workaround, but the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you resolve the problem, I also had problems with the particle system disappearing when using geometry nodes. Here's how it worked out in my project. I think whatever it is you're trying to do you have to output actual geometry from geometry nodes and then apply the particle system, or alternatively make a particle system in the geometry nodes itself.

My screen:
[image: my screen]